# how to show previous image in java applet on repaint

Tags: java

//here is the code

/* in this program i want whenever i click new image should be created depends upon selection of image and keep falling down but here is the problem if i click again for another image it repaints entire screen and previous image is cleared. How to create new Image evrytime i click on screen and keep previous image*/

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class PickAndDrop extends Applet implements Runnable, MouseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Image image, background, box, brick, stone;

    Graphics second;

    boolean mouse = false;


    int posx, posy;

    public void init() {

        setSize(990, 640);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        addMouseListener(this);

        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("PickAndDrop");

        background = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "bg.png");
        box = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "box.png");
        brick = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "brick.png");
        stone = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "stone.png");

    }

    public void start() {

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }

    public void stop() {

    }

    public void destroy() {

    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {

        if (image == null) {
            image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            second = image.getGraphics();
        }

        second.setColor(getBackground());
        second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        second.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(second);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);

        g.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
        g.drawRect(100, 50, 50, 50);
        g.drawRect(150, 50, 50, 50);

        g.drawImage(box, 50, 50, this);
        g.drawImage(brick, 100, 50, this);
        g.drawImage(stone, 150, 50, this);

        if (mouse == true) {

            if (posy < 455) {
                posy++;

                g.drawImage(box, posx, posy, this);

            } else if (posy >= 455) {
                g.drawImage(box, posx, 455, this);

            }

        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        posx = x;
        posy = y;

        mouse = true;

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {


    }

}
```

Comment: Make a list of points you clicked and draw the images at all those locations in order.

Comment: i am sorry to ask such a noob question but can you elaborate more how to do that..?

Comment: When a click is registered add the point that was clicked to a list. In your paint method draw the corresponding images for every point in that list.

Comment: well i think even then also "repaint()" method will erase previous point location. how to stop repaint erasing previous location of image?